# extendscript: get Filepath of Project

Tags: javascript, path, directory, extendscript, after-effects

Iam trying to get the current Filepath of my After Effects project (not Jsx)

```
  var path=app.project['file'];
```

this variable "path" is giving me the a current FileObject name but it is a File-Object not a String. I need the alert as String. Or is there even a better way to get the Path as String?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `File Object` in the Object Model Viewer within Extendscript Toolkit or [here](http://yearbook.github.io/esdocs/#/Javascript/File).

```
if(app.project.file !== null){
    var path = app.project.file.fsName;
    $.writeln(path);
}
```

Comment: Beware, `Returns File object or null if project has not been saved; read-only.` (from: https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/general/project/#project-file)